Galois group of shimura varieties with different level structure
Let $(G,X)$ be a shimura data, and $K$ an open compact neat subgroup of $G(\mathbb A_f)$. Suppose $K'\subset K$ is open and normal, then, I see in many references that the finite etale cover $Sh(G,X)_{K'}$ over $Sh(G,X)_{K}$ is Galois, with Galois group $K/K'$. It's very weird to me, since both $Sh(G,X)_{K}$ and $Sh(G,X)_{K'}$ are not necessarily connected, so what's the meaning of "Galois group"?

Maybe that one is (better: has the structure of) a $K/K'$-torsor over the other? This makes sense regardless of whether the spaces are connected.

A technical point: this assertion is not true for all Shimura varieties, primarily because of the existence of integral points of infinite order in the center. A basic example is when the group is the restriction of scalars of $GL_2$ from a totally real field.
